# How do I render HTML elements on the index page of a ghost blog?

Tags: ghost-blog

Is there a way to make the post preview on the index page render like the permalink page?

Just to be clear the index page excerpts the first few lines in plain text. The permalink page displays the content withing HTML elements.

I understand that this is probably by design, but it occasionally makes a post preview illegible.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please add an example or otherwise clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

**What the Excerpt!?**

With Ghost an *excerpt* is a small preview of a posts content, usually included on the index page. The *excerpt* is stripped of any HTML elements and rendered as a string:

```
{{excerpt words="50"}}
```

**Show the Content**

It is possible the content, with HTML elements included, on the index page. Replace the code above with the following:

```
{{content words="50"}}
```

**Use with caution!**

As `words="50"` of *content* includes HTML elements and words, you may end up with unclosed HTML elements.